# Copying the HTML element object form Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to copy the HTML element **object** from Chrome developer tools. When I hover my mouse over the HTML element, then it shows me the element as an object.

When I inspect it in the console then it shows me the element rendered as HTML.

If I then do a copy(this.input) then it copies the rendered HTML (not the actual object)

How do I get the **object**?

[image]

Comment: For anyone else who may not know, [`copy`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#copy) is part of Chrome's devtools Command Line API.

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What would you do with the object once you had a copy of it in your clipboard? If we know what that is, we may be able to help you do it in some other way.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#copy), `copy` specifically copies a string representation:

> `copy(object)` copies **a string representation** of the specified object to the clipboard.

*(my emphasis)*

Copying the actual object would require that your clipboard contain data from the DOM memory of the browser. Typically that's not possible. Clipboards can contain various standard formats (text, obviously; rich text sometimes; the locations of files; image data in various formats; etc.), but I don't believe it's possible to copy the actual object data from the DOM into your clipboard. (If it is possible, which I doubt, I don't see anything in the Command Line API that does it.) The standard representation for a DOM element is, of course, HTML, so it makes sense for Chrome to copy that to the clipboard, even though of course converting to HTML is lossy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/#current, try use `$0`